# How to open file through flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Is there any way to open a file or folder (default file browser) in flutter?

I can't find any plugin to do with this, and it takes me a long time to find a solution

I tried plugins like [open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file) & [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) etc.

they all don't work

Comment: Can you share the exact problem / error faced by you with open_file / url_launcher package?

Comment: `exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()`
and i tried to set `FileProvider` in my AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: open_file seems can only open some files, and cannot jump to the file manager

Comment: Can you share Code Snippet? It can be easier to identify.

Comment: like `launch('file:/path')` or` OpenFile.open('/path')`

Answer (score 0):

AFAK, you can use the plugin [open_filex](https://pub.dev/packages/open_filex). It is a fork of [open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file) and well maintained compared to other forks. I've tested the [example](https://pub.dev/packages/open_filex/example) and it's working just fine:

[image]